# Android SDK - running functions in the background

Tags: java, android, multithreading, function, sdk

I have a function which can vary in the time it takes to finish. I would like to display a progress dialog whilst this function is operating.

I am aware that you can use a 'Thread' to achieve this. Can someone point me in the right direction for doing this ?

EDIT:
Here is the code I am using:

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    public Context context;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (!dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.show(); // Just in case
        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Working", "Getting amenity information", true);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onProgressUpdate(Progress[])
     */
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
      // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
     }
}
```

this is the Asnyc class. The user selects an option from the menu, and this is then executed:

```
longOperation.execute(""); // Start Async Task

GetAmenities(Trails.UserLocation); // Long function operation
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `AsyncTask` for this purpose. See [Android developers website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [How to use AsyncTask](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/82805.aspx).

Some sample code:

```
private class LongRunningTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog progress;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(yourContext, "Title", "Text");
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return true;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result) {
           progress.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the method I have used although the progress dialog still shows up after the functions in my app have finished ?

Comment: @Jamie: Post your source code and edit your question. It's hard to tell why your dialog doesn't show up without source.

Comment: Well basically, when the user selects a menu option, the app executes the AsyncTask then the function starts doing its stuff - the app locks up while this task is being completed then carries on afterward in which the dialog pops up and dimisses straight away

Comment: @Jamie: "*AsyncTask then the function starts doing its stuff*" doesn't tell me what's causing the error. Post source code - I'm sure you're using it wrong.

Comment: @Jamie: Your function operation must operate inside `doInBackground`.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case - thank you for your help, I will do that and post the result.

Comment: Success, works beautifully. Also, I have noticed a sudden performance boost - Does processing big functions in the background normally perform better ?

Comment: @Jamie: Maybe it feels that way since `AsyncTask` is performing in a background thread and your UI thread isn't blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page:

[Progress Bar Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)

Greetings

Answer (score -1):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Bitmap b = loadImageFromNetwork();

    }
  }).start();
}
```

taken from here
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: no! You cannot modify views from outside the UI thread. Use `AsyncTask` or `Handler`s to do that.

Comment: yeah as fixing that as you commented.

Comment: And right below that blurb on the link it says do NOT do it that way.