# Running a function in the background on Android

Tags: android, firebase

I have a function that I want to execute in the background even when the application is closed.

So this is my function:

```
 public void test() {

    String tkn = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    String text = chat_msg;
    not();
    Log.d("App", "Token[" + tkn + "]");

}


public void not() {

    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notification.setAutoCancel(true);

    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.downloadfile);
    notification.setTicker("This is the tocken");
    notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setContentTitle(user_name);
    notification.setContentText(chat_msg);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Chat_Room.this, Message.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());

}
```

So about my application and this function - I have created a chat application that uses Firebase. Everytime a user sends a message a notification will be send to all users in the chat.

The functions works while the app is open and when in background. But when the app is closed (completely) no notification. How do I implement a service that will execute this function?

Also how do I put a counter for unread messages - for example when multiple messages are sent instead of showing message it will show a number that represent unread messages.

Comment: you can use alarm manager for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you give a try to use Broadcast receivers, Async Tasks
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Similar Stackoverflow threads:
1. [How to run a function background in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445202/how-to-run-a-function-background-in-android)

2. [Android SDK - running functions in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168748/android-sdk-running-functions-in-the-background)

Comment: You should paraphrase the linked articles, in case the links get broken for whatever reason.

Comment: oh. i think async will do the jobs for me. but tjust to make sure. 1. async is a service that executes a set of codes eg in my case will send notification to users.